# Auto-redirect to a url containing a random number

Tags: redirect, random, numbers

There has been some questions on how to generate random numbers in URL links on this site, but what I am trying to do is when someone visits the website , it automatically redirects them to www.example.com/index.php?9999999 (where 9999999 is a 6 digit random number).

I am not getting anywhere with this so far. Can it be done?

Thanks a bunch in advance,
Fraser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a 6 digit random number, this should be good

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/index.php?'.rand(100000,999999)) ;

?>
```

Place it on the page from which you want people to redirect